# Prevent multiple user logging into the same domain using the same browser

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, sessionid, session-cookies

So its a ASP.NET problem where two users using the same machine, same browser.

1. User 1 logs in the domain.
2. User 1 changes some data without saving it.
3. User 2 logs in the domain in a separate tab.
4. User 1 switches back to his tab and saves the data.
5. User 1 actually saved the data into User 2!!

This is caused by the following mechanism:

1. Different tabs in the same browser seems to share the same session id.
2. We are storing user auth in cookie and the cookie is shared between tabs (same domain)

Therefore, when User 1 request to save, it is recognized as User 2 since the cookie has been updated to User 2.

So I'm wondering if there's any other methods to prevent this from happening, other than:
1. Use cookieless session so the session is embedded in uri.
2. Always include a hidden field in page to indicate which user owns the page.

Regards,

Comment: Have them use different browsers - one can use IE the other Firefox. Problem solved.

Comment: I understand it is completely fine when different browser is used, which is why I stated in the question that they're using the same machine, same browser, just different tabs.

Comment: Similar problem have google pages also... and probably more sites...

Comment: I noticed that gmail actually have some mechanism for the scenario I described; it pops up an alert message indicating "This may have happened automatically because another user signed in from the same browser" and logs the previous user out automatically. Anyone know how it is done?

Comment: Hi BlueFox, I know it's been a while but I am having same issue. Did you find a conclusion to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could add some fields in the database to track that the user is logged in, and grab their IP address, and restrict access that way.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure how IP address would help since they're using the same machine & browser (ie, same IP).

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a "New Session" command in the file menu that opens a new window, but that's pretty much like using 2 different browsers.

Hiding the login form until the current user is logged out will raise awareness that another user is logged in but won't prevent the above scenario.  If the logout process could refresh each page in the browser on the domain then it might work, although user1 would loose all modified data.

Comment: I like your second proposal of hiding the login form until the current user is logged out to raise awareness, but could you elaborate on how should one go about implementing "logout process to refresh each page in the browser on the domain"?

Comment: I am not sure if it is even possible but if there is a way to iterate though all open windows with the same origin using javascript, you could call the `window.location.reload()` function on each one.

Answer (score 0):

I used the trick of opening a new window with a specific name and always make sure that any page will open always use that window.